# Show last row on line hovering

Tags: html, css

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content1</td>
      <td>Content2</td>
      <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content3</td>
      <td>Content4</td>
      <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content5</td>
      <td>Content6</td>
      <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

tr > td:last-child {
  display: none;
}

tr:hover > td:last-child {
  display: block;
}
```

Hovering on row to show last column works fine [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5x2wv160)

I'm trying to show the *last row when the mouse hovers on the first row (or maybe header)* but my below code doesn't work. Any idea what's going wrong?

```
tr:last-child {
  display: none;
}

th:hover > tr:last-child {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Please add or show what your end goal is, as it is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The greater-than symbol is a child selector, but a `tr` cannot be a child of a `th`:

```
th:hover > tr:last-child {
  display: block;
}
```

Instead, you can use the general sibling selector (~) with the `thead` element, which will grab the `tbody`'s last row, like this:

```
thead:hover ~ * tr:last-child {
  display: table-row;
}
```

**Example:**

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

tbody tr:last-child {
  display: none;
}

thead:hover ~ * tr:last-child {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content1</td>
      <td>Content2</td>
      <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content3</td>
      <td>Content4</td>
      <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content5</td>
      <td>Content6</td>
      <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```